# Add string param to array

Tags: powershell

I have a simple problem. I'm trying to solve my problem below. I hope someone can help and guide me on my problem.

I want to add a string to an array in a function. Here's my function.

```
function myFunc {
    Param(
    [string]$Logs,
    [string]$Status
    )
    
    if ($Status -eq $True) {
        $logsArray += $Logs
        Write-Host "Completed!`n" -ForegroundColor Green
        $logsArray
        } else {
        $logsArray += $Logs
    }
}
```

If I try to enter these 3 strings

```
myFunc -Logs "[Success] Test 1" -Status $False
myFunc -Logs "[Success] Test 2" -Status $False
myFunc -Logs "[Success] Test Final" -Status $True
```

The only result I'm getting is

```
Completed!

[Success] Test Final
```

and this is what I want to get

```
Completed!

[Success] Test 1
[Success] Test 2
[Success] Test Final
```

Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From feedback provided in comments, it seems that what you are actually looking to do is to collect all input and output all once the argument to `-Status` is `$true`. For that you have two options, but note, this is not a common pattern you should follow from PowerShell perspective as the UX is not great if this is meant to be shared. Its very likely the problem you're facing could be solved in a cleaner way.

1. Define an array or list at [script scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers) from within your function and check in each function call that its not previously defined (to not overwrite it):

```
function myFunc {
    Param(
        [string] $Logs,
        [bool] $Status
    )

    if(-not $Script:LogsArray) {
        $Script:LogsList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    }

    $Script:LogsList.Add($Logs)

    if ($Status) {
        Write-Host "Completed!`n" -ForegroundColor Green
        $Script:LogsList
    }
}

myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test 1' -Status $False
myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test 2' -Status $False
myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test Final' -Status $True
```

2. Second option is to define the list or array **outside the function**, in which case the if condition can be removed:

```
$LogsList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

function myFunc {
    Param(
        [string] $Logs,
        [bool] $Status
    )

    $LogsList.Add($Logs)

    if ($Status) {
        Write-Host "Completed!`n" -ForegroundColor Green
        $LogsList
    }
}

myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test 1' -Status $False
myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test 2' -Status $False
myFunc -Logs '[Success] Test Final' -Status $True
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I want to show the output when the $Status was set to $True.

Comment: @sjqwer1 the expected output you're showing in your question indicates the opposite, you want to show the output either way. unless you're looking to collect all input and output all at once when `-Status` is `$true` ?

Comment: Sorry. I should have made it clear in my question. Correct. output all at once when `-Status` is `$True`

Comment: @sjqwer1 is that what you were looking for? to collect all input and output all when Status is True?

Comment: Yes @Santiago Squarzon

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll choose option 2 as it seems easier to understand. Thank you so much for you help!